# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'about' not found. 'about' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am building blog in django and stuck because of this error.
When I click on Readmore button to load full blog post. this error appears.
it should load the page which diplay blog post with detail it showed this error to me.
i tried different solutions which are available on internet but didn't get rid of this error.

[image]

Here is my code!

project url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', include('Blog_App.urls')),
]
```

app urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name= 'home'),
      path('user/<str:username>/', views.UserPostList.as_view(), name= 'user-posts'),
      path('<slug:slug>', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name= 'post_detail'),
      path('register/', views.Register, name= 'Registration'),
      path('login/', views.Login, name= 'Login'),
      path('logout/', views.logout_view, name= 'Logout'),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.db import models
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import  AuthenticationForm
from django.views import generic
from .models import STATUS, Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostList(generic.ListView):
     queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
     template_name = 'Blog_App/index.html'

class UserPostList(generic.ListView):
     model = Post
     template_name = 'Blog_App/user_posts.html'
     context_object_name = 'posts'

def get_queryset(self):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-created_on')
    
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'Blog_App/post_detail.html'

def Register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           user = form.save()
           login(request, user)
           messages.success(request, 'Registration succesfull')
           return redirect('home')
       messages.error(request, 'Invalid Information')
    form = NewUserForm()
    context = {'register_form': form}
    return render(request, 'Blog_App/register.html', context )

def Login(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, 'Congrats. You logged In! ')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Incorrect Credentials!')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Information')

  form = AuthenticationForm()
  return render(request, 'Blog_App/login.html', context={'login_form': form})


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.info(request, 'You are succesfully Logged out')
    return redirect('home')
```

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog-App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <nav class="test">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material- 
                 icons">menu</i></a>
              <ul id="nav-mobile" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="badges.html">About </a></li>
                  <li><a href="badges.html">Contact Us</a></li>
               <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
               {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <li><a href="{% url 'Logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">{{user.username}}</a></li>
               {% else %}
                  <li><a href="{% url 'Login' %}">Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url 'Registration' %}">Register</a></li>
              {% endif %}
             </ul>
        <div>
       </nav>
          
   </div>
{% block content %}    

{% endblock content %}   


<footer class="page-footer" >
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col l6 s12">
      <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
      <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your 
       footer content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
      <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="footer-copyright">
  <div class="container">
  © 2014 Copyright Text
  <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    {% if messages %}
       {% for msg in messages %}  
          <script>
            swal({
               "text": "{{msg}}",
            });
          </script>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="Blog-posts">
   <div class="row">
    
       <div class="div-1">
          <div class="col s12 m6 ">
             {% for post in post_list %}
                  <div class="card card-list blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                       <div class="author">
                          <a href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">
                             <h5 class="author-name"><img class="author-img" src="{% static 
                              'images/profile.jpg' %}" alt="" height="40px" width="40px">
                                {{post.author}}</h5>
                          </a>
                             <small class="post-created_on">{{post.created_on}}</small>
          
          
                          </div>
                       <span class="card-title">{{post.title}}</span>
                       <p>{{post.content|slice:"200"}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Readmore-btn">
                       <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}" class="waves-effect waves- 
                        light btn-small">Read More</a></div>
          
                  </div>
          
             {% endfor %}
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="div-2">
          <div class="col m5">
                <div class="card card-sidebar">
                  <div class="card-content black-text">
                    <span class="card-title">About Us</span>
                    <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of 
                     information.
                    I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-action">
                    <div class="Readmore-btn_about"><a href="#" class="waves-effect waves- 
                     light btn-small">Read More</a>
          
          
              </div>
       </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use this line `{% url "about" %}` somewhere in your **base.html** template - but you don't have any paths in your urlpatterns with this name. However, I don't see this in your code you've shared - are you sure you have the correct file?

Comment: yeah. that's accurate code which i write in base.html. That's what i am confused i don't have any pattern like {% url 'about' %} in base file but why he giving me this error

Comment: [This may help](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/reverse-for-login-not-found-login-is-not-a-valid-view-function-or-pattern-name/2396/7).

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing same kind of issue. so here how i get rid of this.
Django giving me error of some kind of {% url 'about' %} pattern in base.html.
But it actually exist in another html file which called as post_detail.html.
So if you are facing same kind of error check for other files as well you will find an error in other html file.
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).